# SQL join and aggregate function

Tags: sql

I require a query for the following statement:

Show the details of all staff who have booked more than 4 vehicle rentals for customers.

The schema is as follows:

```
Staff (staffID, firstname, lastname, xyz..)

Customers (customerID, firstname, lastname, xyz..)

Booking (bookingID, staffID, customerID, vehicleregistration, date)

Vehicle (vehicleregistration, make, model, xyz..)
```

Cheers!

Comment: We're here to help you get your skills better, not to do your coding for you. Try upwork if you need somebody to write code. This also sounds very much like a homework question to me.

Comment: Looks like kind of homework. Have you even try to do something?

Comment: I understand the join but I am not sure on aggregate and join. I was thinking something along the lines of:

Comment: @Ableman update your question with your current code so we can see what you're missing, it's better not to post code in the comments.

Comment: you have not mentioned about which database because different database has different kind inbuilt feature and based on feature query may be changed.
based on given few detail in question,   group by and having may be required for your solution.

Comment: I'm too old for homework. Had it for an exam though and want to check my understanding and better my knowledge.. I understand the join but I am not sure on aggregate and join. I was thinking something along the lines of joining staffid between the tables, count the bookingid as an alias and group by staffid where alias is greater than x. Does that sound about right?

Comment: if you are using sql server, follow this url:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23663/total-of-orders-open-on-a-given-date-for-each-date-in-a-date-range

Comment: select staff.*, count(bookingid) from booking as A where (staff.staffid=booking.staffid) group by staff.staffid having A > 4;

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag the DBMS used, show sample data and sample results. Anyway, I guess I understand what you are looking for and have given an answer in standard SQL that should run on all DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that *all* Booking records are actual vehicle rentals for customers. So you want to count these per staff. *per staff* translates to `GROUP BY staffid`. To check aggregation results (the count) you'd use the `HAVING` clause.

```
select * 
from staff
where staffid in
(
  select staffid
  from booking
  group by staffid
  having count(*) > 4
);
```

As you see, there is no need to join anything, as you only want data from the staff table. The booking count is criteria that better belongs in the `WHERE` clause.

Just for completeness sake, here is the same with a join:

```
select s.* 
from staff s
join
(
  select staffid
  from booking
  group by staffid
  having count(*) > 4
) b on b.staffid = s.staffid;
```

I find this less readable, but some people may prefer it still. You'd use this if you wanted to show information from the aggregation in your results, in your case the count.

```
select s.*, b.bookings
from staff s
join
(
  select staffid, count(*) as bookings
  from booking
  group by staffid
  having count(*) > 4
) b on b.staffid = s.staffid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT staffID,COUNT(vehicleregistration) FROM Staff JOIN Booking ON Staff.staffID = Booking.staffID JOIN Vehicle ON Vehicle.vehicleregistration = Booking.vehicleregistration GROUP BY staffID HAVING COUNT(vehicleregistration) > 4
```